# LambdaContext object has no attribute getRemainingTimeInMillis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('test')
    print(context.getRemainingTimeInMillis())
```

Error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'LambdaContext' object has no attribute 'getRemainingTimeInMillis'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError"
}
```

This is working on other functions with the same python3.9 runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getRemainingTimeInMillis()` is for `nodejs`. For **python** it should be:

```
context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()
```